# Bash - variable case statement options based on parsed CSV?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, menu

Ok I am stumped, but surely this is possible..

Say you have options.csv that looks like

```
ID, option
1, something
2, something else
3, you get the point
4, fin
```

And I want to parse those items out to use as user selectable items in a case statement, thus making the  statement essentially variable if the CSV were to change. I imagine I can parse the file with read and an IFS=, but I am lost as to how to take what would be parsed into a user selectable menu.

Is such a thing possible in bash? Surely I would think it is, but I'm at a loss of how to implement. Bonus if ID column of the CSV matches up to the selection input from the case statement.

@Cyrus has gotten me on the right track.

Something like this? Though I know the syntax is off:

```
#read csv file to an array and ignore header
mapfile -t array < <(awk -F ', ' 'NR>1{print $2}' $file)

    #Use array to map values to selection menu
    select name in "${array[@]}";do echo "$name" >> item.list; done
    cat $sysBanner > itemMenu && cat item.list >> itemMenu && echo -e "\n\n" >> itemMenu
    cat itemMenu
    read -p "Item to select:  "
    case $itemSelected in

            @)    echo -e "\nOK, $name selected.\n"
            sleep 1 && clear
            componentName=$name
            ;;
            * )     echo "invalid selection. Please try again."
            ;;
    esac
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

With bash and awk:

```
# Read data to an array and ignore header
mapfile -t array < <(awk -F ', ' 'NR>1{print $2}' file.csv)

# Use array with select command
select name in "${array[@]}"; do echo "$name"; done
```

Output:

```
1) something
2) something else
3) you get the point
4) fin
#?
```

I assume that the numbers in the file always start with 1 and are sorted in ascending order.

Comment: thanks @cyrus. The first part is awesome. Still struggling with the second part however, to put each item into a case statement. See edited answer above please as the comment was too long.

Comment: This might help: [Can I change how select options are displayed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203309/74329)

Comment: thanks - even if you wen that route, however, aren't your case options still fixed?